# (Android Cordova App) document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false); gets not called when phone is locked or home button clicked)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to stop my media when the user presses the home button or the power button. However it seems not to work with the lines of code below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            function onLoad() {
            alert('onLoad');
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }

            // device APIs are available
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
            alert('Device Ready');
                // Register the event listener
                document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
            }

            // Handle the pause event
            //
            function onPause() {
            alert('on Pause');
        stopAud();
        }
        </script>
```

The first two function are displaying the alert but the third is not and the media is still playing in the background. (If I call the stopAud(); function with a button it will stop the audio.)

Is here please someone who can help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you already searched for your problem? I have already found  relating issues to yours afters seconds, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225694/phonegap-cordova-pause-event-triggered-on-resume-for-android-can-not-turn-off) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822003/cordova-pause-event-not-firing)

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Yeah, I already searched before and even found the same pages like you but even if I set <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/> or false it won't call the onPause() function when I press the home or lock button

Comment: Please read the answer by qefzec on my second link. This should be your answer unfortunately

Comment: Hi thanks, I just updated cordova and it worked then. Thanks again