# Cordova: Hybrid iOS App Pause event doesn't get fired when making a phone call

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

Does the iOS app go to the background when we make the call using tel://123456789 ?

I have an iOS app that requires to log any outbound event happening through our app (like sending mail, calling, etc).

**For Calling**

we use some thing like : `<a href="tel://123456789"></a>`

in this case dialler opens up and makes the call but pause or resume events never gets 
   triggered . So basically we dont have hook/event after the call was ended to make the log 
   entry for call .
   Though while replicating the same flow on android proper events(resume, pause) gets fired.

**For Mail**

we use some thing like :  `<a href="mailto: test@test.com"></a>`

in this case mail client of the user gets opened and our hybrid app goes to background and once mail is sent and the user returns to the app "resume" event gets fired

We need something similar for the phone call. Any pointers will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the pause event is not fired in your app when the phone is switching to the dialer app on iOS only?

Comment: Yes pause event doesn't gets fired for iOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cordova: Pause event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822003/cordova-pause-event-not-firing)

Comment: No it doesn't , I have a issue only when we try to make Phone Call by clicking on anchor tag ```<a href="tel://123456789"></a>``` in that case phone dialler app launches and make the call but neither of the events(onPause or onResume) gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to listen to the click on the a tag then trigger that event yourself if it is not triggered by Cordova, that way you don't have to change your code. Using jQuery:

```
 $('your_a_tag').on('touchstart', function(event){
      $(document).trigger('pause');
 });
```

Alternatively, you could open a support ticket on [cordova-ios](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios) repo.

Comment: ```$(document).trigger('pause');```  does nothing 
    try {
            $(document).trigger('pause');
        } catch (error) {
            alert('error in triggering pause ' + error);
        }

also no error

Comment: That means that your listener for the 'pause' event is not set properly

Comment: $(document).bind("pause", onPause);  rigester the event and triggers the pause event on anchor click  but when call gets ended , resume event doesn't get fired.
Basically we need a event when call gets ended.


Though Apache cordova docs(https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#endcallbutton) mentions about **startcallbutton** and **endcallbutton** events but they are not yet supported for ios and android

Comment: If you are trying to make something that log phone calls duration, this is the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: I am not trying to log phone calls duration , but we want log the call(contact details).
Just out of curiosity whats the correct way of log phone calls duration.